# Android : Unable to start activity Component Info

Tags: android

I've got a problem with my Android App.
I'm trying to communicate in a serial way between my Android-Device and my PC.
That for im using Android NDK.
As soon as i start to use methods using serialport s im getting the error message. either .getSerialPort() or .getOutputStream()

Of course i've allready tried to fix this problem via google.
But actually i didnt found a fix to my problem yet.
I checked if my manifest contains everything needed and im pretty sure it does.
Hopefully someone of you can find the problem in my code.

This is the first time im asking a question on stackoverflow, so i'm up for hints how to ask in a better way in the future.
If any informations are missing, tell me and i'll post them asap.

This is my mainactivity:

```
package com.example.serialtest3;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.serialtest3.SerialPort;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;
EditText et;    
SerialPort s;

protected OutputStream out= new OutputStream() {

@Override
public void write(int oneByte) throws IOException {
}
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    out = s.getOutputStream(); 
    try {
        s.getSerialPort();                        
    } catch (InvalidParameterException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

            String text = et.getText().toString();
            if (v.getId()==R.id.button1){
                try {
                out.write(new String(text).getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });

    et =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editT);
}
```

SerialPort:

```
package com.example.serialtest3;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.InvalidParameterException;
import android.util.Log;
import com.example.serialtest3.*;

public class SerialPort {

private static final String TAG = "SerialPort";
SerialPort serial;
/*
 * Do not remove or rename the field mFd: it is used by native method close();
 */
private FileDescriptor mFd;
private FileInputStream mFileInputStream;
private FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream;

public SerialPort(File device, int baudrate, int flags) throws SecurityException, IOException {

    /* Check access permission */
    if (!device.canRead() || !device.canWrite()) {
        try {
            /* Missing read/write permission, trying to chmod the file */
            Process su;
            su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/su");
            String cmd = "chmod 666 " + device.getAbsolutePath() + "\n"
                    + "exit\n";
            su.getOutputStream().write(cmd.getBytes());
            if ((su.waitFor() != 0) || !device.canRead()
                    || !device.canWrite()) {
                throw new SecurityException();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SecurityException();
        }
    }

    mFd = open(device.getAbsolutePath(), baudrate, flags);
    if (mFd == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "native open returns null");
        throw new IOException();
    }
    mFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mFd);
    mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFd);

}

public SerialPort getSerialPort() throws SecurityException, IOException, InvalidParameterException {
    String path = "/dev/ttyO0";
    int baudrate= 115200;
    serial = new SerialPort(new File(path), baudrate, 0);
    return serial;
}

// Getters and setters
public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return mFileInputStream;
}

public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
    return mFileOutputStream;
}

// JNI
private native static FileDescriptor open(String path, int baudrate, int flags);
public native void close();
static {
    System.loadLibrary("serial_port");  // this lib contains open and close method which are written in the c-code
}
```

}

android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.serialtest3"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.serialtest3.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

error messages:

```
01-01 04:03:29.451: D/AndroidRuntime(2370): Shutting down VM
01-01 04:03:29.451: W/dalvikvm(2370): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a421f8)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.serialtest3/com.example.serialtest3.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at com.example.serialtest3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-01 04:03:29.451: E/AndroidRuntime(2370):     ... 11 more
01-01 04:04:56.035: D/AndroidRuntime(2421): Shutting down VM
01-01 04:04:56.035: W/dalvikvm(2421): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a421f8)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.serialtest3/com.example.serialtest3.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at com.example.serialtest3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-01 04:04:56.035: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     ... 11 more
01-01 04:05:03.232: I/Process(2421): Sending signal. PID: 2421 SIG: 9
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editT"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:lines="1" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SerialPort s;
```

This is not initialized. So this will be pointing to null. That is why it is throwing `Null Pointer Exception`

Comment: this solved my error.
thank you alot :)

i was just to blind to see it :/

Comment: Try to improve your debugging skill,  these are straightforward errors. Try to go through the debug log and trace out the line which is causing the issue.